# Signing issues while migrating Xcode 7.3.5 project to Xcode 8

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, xcode8

I have some issues after downloading the new Xcode. I can't sign my application and always get these errors:

```
Provisioning profile "PROFILE" doesn't include signing certificate "iPhone Developer: DEVELOPER_NAME (ID)".
```

On the Developer Portal I have the following certificates and provisioning profiles:

- iOS Development Certificate
- iOS Distribution Certificate
- iOS Development Provisioning Profile
- iOS UniversalDistribution Provisioning Profile

---

This is how it looks on Xcode:

**When I choose the Debug &  Release signing as Universal Distribution (In-House):**
[image]

**When I choose the signing as Development:**
[image]

**This occurs:**
[image]

What can be the cause of it? does anyone have a clue?

Answer (score 0):

My project also encounter this problem. in General，i choose "Automatically manage signing" solve this question.[enter image description here][1]